# Registering a provider in module Vs component/directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

We can register a provider either in angular module or in component / custom directive?

Why angular team allowed to register a provider either at module or component / custom directive? Can someone help with practical example with pros and cons?

Comment: I didn't want to also provide an answer as to not step on any toes, but I wanted to add this: Registration in a module _scopes a service_ to the _execution context of the running module_. Any component created within that execution context has access to one of its services.

Registration in a component _scopes the service_ availability to that _component and its sub-tree of components_.

Comment: Under the hood there are actually two different injector hierarchies: one for modules and one for components.  When searching for a service, the component injector hierarchy takes precedence. If the service is not found, then DI looks at the module injector hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why angular team allowed to register a provider either at module or
> component / custom directive?

That's because they have different scope. The provider registered at the non-lazy loaded module level will be available for any component in the entire application. The provider registered at the component level is available only for the component and its children.

Having worked for a few years with AngularJS where there was only one application level scope I see the current Angular scoped injectors implementation as a great step forward. To understand the benefits better suppose you're developing a dashboard with widgets. The UI looks like this:

[image]

So you want to have a special class responsible for each widget management. And you want all the components inside the widget to get the instance of the service specific to their widget. In AngularJS this would be very difficult to accomplish because if we register this service at the application level only one instance will be created. But in Angular this problem is easily solved. We register the service at the WidgetComponent and then children of this component will inject their own instance of the service.

Comment: You only mention non-lazy modules, but I'd add that you can also register provider on a lazy loaded module. Let's call the module `M` and provider `P`. In such situation `P` will be available to all the components in `M` and all their children components. How that differs from registering `P` in one of the components declared in module `M` is that `P` is available to other components in the module `M` and that there is a single instance `P` across all the components instances (when you register `P` in a component, each component instance gets separate instance of `P`).

Answer (score 4):

Well, The two ways to register the providers are :

1. Module level
2. Component level

**Module level providers :**

It is certain that you will have many components listed under the same module. So by providing the service at module level, all the components under that module can access the service directly.

**Component/Directive level providers :**

If you provide services at component level then only that particular component and it's child component tree can interact with it. No other components can interact with that service.

One pro I can think of here is the accessibility. Providing the service at component level will make the service available only to that component.

Say that you want a service S to be accessed only by Component C1 but not C2, C3 and all three are under the same module M and are at the same level. In this case you can provide the service at component C1. So that C2 and C3 cannot access it or reach it. If you want a shared service which should be utilized by all components C1, C2 and C3, then you should provide service S in module M.

Comment: See the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#when-to-use-ngmodule-versus-an-application-component and I'll post an answer explaining why this is incorrect.

Comment: So does the document says. On the one hand, a provider in an NgModule is registered in the root injector. That means that every provider registered within an NgModule will be accessible in the entire application.

On the other hand, a provider registered in an application component is available only on that component and all its children

Comment: My explanation is the same. May be I have not put it properly.

Comment: Yes, above you said `No other components can interact with that service.` in your comment above you corrected it to `or its children`.

Comment: And if you really want to be complete and correct, you should also mention how this is different with lazy loading ...

Comment: I certainly did not consider child components in my explanation. That was a generic description. Anyways I have updated it.

Comment: You mention scope of the provider (module level providers are avaible across all components in that module, component level providers are available only in a single component), but there is also difference in instantiating. Module level provider creates only 1 instance for the whole module (so each component in that module gets the same instance of the provider), while separate component level providers instance is created for each instance of the component.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

This annotation is provided above the service class.
This is available from Angular 6 version. prior to that i.e from Angular 2 to 5 we need to provide the service in providers in appModule.ts

i.e like providers: [Servicename] in `appModule.ts`

When we provide the service in the component metadata i.e in `@Component` decorator by giving providers: `[Servicename]`,
then the service is only for that component, but not for remaining components in the project.